# How can I get exact colors of PNG in android?

Tags: android, png, bitmapfactory

I work on a 3d map.Save elevation data as png.
But when decode the PNG in android,I can not get the exact colors. 
E.g. pixel (100, 50) has the color RGB(100, 10, 100). I get color like RGB(101, 11, 99),This is my elevation data PNG [123.207.115.60/N22E106/5_4.png](http://123.207.115.60/N22E106/5_4.png)

My code followed:

```
public int[] GetPixelsFromPNG(byte[] PNGData, int dataLen, int wh)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt;
        opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //opt.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
        opt.inDither=true;
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArrayPNGData, 0, dataLen,opt);

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        int pixels[] = new int[width * height];
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return pixels;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? *I can get the exact colors*

Comment: sorry,I can not get the exact colors .

Comment: Now, I will save data biger.  E.G  30 save as (30*4+2)=122.     When I decode maybe 121  or 123,   123%4=30,  exact.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English :(

Comment: Can we have the sample PNG ?

Comment: Any PNG. This is my elevation data PNG  http://123.207.115.60/N22E106/5_4.png

Comment: elevation data PNG  [link](http://123.207.115.60/N22E106/5_4.png)

Comment: What's the intent of `opt.inDither=true;`?  Try removing that line.

Comment: Remove the line ,the color is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems a problem related to the "color profile" specified in the png file. The problem was resolved just opening the file with Gimp and exporting it.